# My discord bot is not responding to any commands in replit (Python)

Tags: python, discord, chatbot

I am a beginner at programming and just recently started using python. I'm trying to create a discord bot in an IDE called replit. Replit doesn't seem to be detecting errors since it lets me run the code without underlining or pointing any lines out. However, when I run the bot and type the command into discord the bot does not respond. When I go back to replit, it still doesn't detect any errors or point anything out in the console. I tried making bot commands in two different formats. The first one (in which the user says hello and the bot responds) works but the other two commands after that have multiple responses in which the bot is supposed to choose a randomized response from that list. Those two commands do not work. Here is the code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  if message.content.startswith ('^hello'):
   await message.channel.send('Hello...( ・_・)ノ')

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))

import os
import random
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
#help commands
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='^')
@bot.command(name='help')
async def help(ctx):
    omori_responses = [
        'OMORI’s main command categories are: FUN, CURRENCY, OMORI, SUNNY, BASIL, MARI, HERO, KEL, AUBREY, WHITESPACE, DREAMWORLD, and BLACKSPACE. Please use the command omo help <insert command category>',
        
            'OMORI’s main command categories are: FUN, CURRENCY, OMORI, SUNNY, BASIL, MARI, HERO, KEL, AUBREY, WHITESPACE, DREAMWORLD, and BLACKSPACE. Please use the command omo help <insert command category>' 
          ]
    response = random.choice(omori_responses)
    await ctx.send(response)
client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
#whitespace commands
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='^')
@bot.command(name='ws')
async def white_space(ctx):
    omori_responses = [
        'Whitespace. A single black lightbulb hangs from the ceiling above...wherever above is',
        'Whitespace. You have been here since as far back as you can remember...whenever that is. Everything is bright white. There are no walls. There is a floor...it is always cold.',
        
            'Whitespace. Everything you need is here. A laptop, sketchbook, tissue box, blanket, and MEWO, your cat.',
            'Whitespace. There is a door here. Beyond this door is a colorful world, unlike here...' 
          ]
    response = random.choice(omori_responses)
    await ctx.send(response)
client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Comment: Why do you run the code three times? Your way of ordering is also very questionable. If you are really new I would suggest you read the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) first or watch some tutorials.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, Dominik. I've actually only been using python for 2-3 months and am self-taught. I guess I've skipped some steps, so thank you for the link to the docs, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you write your own [`on_message()` event reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message) (overriding the default discord.py `on_message()`), you need to call the [`Bot.process_commands()` method](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=process_commands#discord.ext.commands.Bot.process_commands).

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith ('^hello'):
       await message.channel.send('Hello...( ・_・)ノ')

    await bot.process_commands(message)
```